# Compute the diameter of any kind of tree?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, pseudocode

How to design an algorithm that computes in linear time the diameter of a (graph theoretical) undirected, all-edges-have-weight-1 tree? The diameter of a tree is given by the length of the longest path between two vertices.

Any idea of how to aproach this problem?

Comment: What do you know about the tree to begin with?  The height, weight, density, uniformity of trunk, circumference of trunk, species, growing conditions, exposure to wind/light, number of rings from a core with weather history for its lifespan, etc?  It's an exceptionally variable bit of data.

Comment: @Orbling Good one, hahah. winston, how do you define diameter of a tree?

Comment: @Orbling nothing, it´s just a tree

Comment: Aye, good point @iccthedral.  When dendrologists note diameter of the tree, they usually take it at a uniform height above the ground (often 1m), or find the widest girth - so that the measurement has some form of uniformity between samples.

Comment: @iccthedral the diameter of a tree is defined as let G=(V,A)be a graph diameter = max{d(x,y): for all x,y in V(G)}

Comment: @winstonsmith: Well the algorithm will be to get a tape measure, walk up to the tree and, possibly enlisting a friend if the tree is broad, wrap the tape around the trunk and note the circumference.  Then take measurements on tangents to the trunk of the extents of the trunk, so you can get an idea of a rectangular containment.  Treat the cross-section of the trunk as an ellipse, knowing the perimeter and major and minor axis lengths and you can establish an average radius from that.

Comment: Haha, for a moment I felt like I was in a center of a joke here :)) I see winston, I denote that as a width of a tree, good thing I asked. I'll try to help. Give me an hour atl.

Comment: @winstonsmith: So this is a graph algorithm, what do your d(x,y) mean, and what are the vertices representing in `G`?

Comment: Do you mean a spanning tree?

Comment: @Orbling yes d(x,y)= diameter -with-

Comment: @Orbling any kind of tree, i just know that is a tree

Comment: If so, just multiply all edge weights by -1 and use [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm).

Comment: @winstonsmith That's not good. You should be given some criteria on the input. What to output in case the graph is a forest? If it's empty? Etc.

Comment: @iccthedral i know... in fact i have a solution for a binary tree, but my TA told me that not necessarily is a binary tree. The only thing i know is that is just a tree :S

Comment: Is it a rooted/directed/undirected tree?

Answer (score 7):

Let v1 be any vertex in the tree.

Do a depth first search from v1 to get the distances of all other vertices from v1, choose v2 as the vertex with the highest distance.

Do a depth first search from v2 to get the distances of all other vertices from v2, choose v3 as the vertex with the highest distance.

D(v2, v3) is the tree diameter. The complexity is O(|V|), as DFS is linear for a tree.